# How to display the join field in a QGIS join?

Tags: qgis

Upon joining tables in QGIS (2.8.2) I am unable to view the join field in the resulting join.  Additionally, the join field is not listed in the target table's Layer Properties, even though the other join table fields are listed there.

I recognize that the target field is displayed, but there are times when I would like to also see the join field.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The join field is not added to the attribute table since it would only duplicate the target field. There seems to be no reason to keep both. Therefore there is no setting to add the duplicate column.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  My reason for keeping both is to be able to quickly switch between outer and inner joins using the queries: target field = join field, or target field <> join field.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I tried to get the target field to display using the Add Vector Join > Choose Which Fields Are Joined option, because the target field is listed.  However, that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a duplicate column of your join field -- in one of the two tables? You can then delete it if you want.